# Checksum different For Same file Created By Two process

Tags: oracle, vb6, checksum, utl-file

I have one utility in VB which generates attached file(circle.14.mdn_range.properties_VB) & i have created other file(circle.14.mdn_range.properties_UTLFILE) having same contents with UTL_FILE(Oracle). But checksum is different for both the files with same contents. Can you suggest the reason & possible way of removing this error?

```
CertUtil -hashfile circle.14.mdn_range.properties_VB MD5
MD5 hash of file circle.14.mdn_range.properties_VB:
1b 43 b6 a4 44 d0 4d 8a 8b 91 3e 7b d7 aa 4f 4e
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.

CertUtil -hashfile circle.14.mdn_range.properties_UTLFILE MD5  
MD5 hash of file circle.14.mdn_range.properties_UTLFILE:

ae 0c 75 b8 d5 19 05 64 d5 c6 54 ec 55 bc dc e0
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Without seeing the data itself and the code that produced it, there's not much we can do to help.  Please [edit] your post to include examples of how you created those files.

Comment: Same file *contents* maybe, but not the same *file* if created by 2 different processes and 2 different ways

Comment: Clearly the files are not the same.

Comment: If the checksums are not the same, the files are not the same. Just because they share the same name or seem like they should be the same doesn't make them so. If I have two manufacturers who both have web pages with links that say "Make me a car", and I click the link on both sites, and both tell me they've shipped me a car, it doesn't mean both cars are the same (or even that they're both cars - one could have two wheels and pedals). Use a diff utility to compare the files and find out where they're different. We can't do that for you, because we don't have the files.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible one of the files is UTF-8 (usually referred to as ASCII) and the other is UTF-16 (usually referred to as Unicode). To identify where the files differ, try a utility like "Beyond Compare". Alternately, it should be trivial to write a VB program to open both files in binary more, read byte by byte and find out where they differ.